# CSS is rendered different in different screen resolutions

Tags: html, forms, css

I have the following html component which is using a booking engine. The component parent width is set and the children are inherited. There are three input fields and a button. The problem is, in different screen resolutions the search button is dropped to the next line or the more search option overlaps the button. CSS is as following.

```
.search-container{
    height: 70px;
    width: 846px;
    position: absolute;
    top:170px;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
}
.outer-container{
    width: 836px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(43, 51, 54, 0.91);
    padding: 5px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='rgba(43, 51, 54, 0.91)', endColorstr='rgba(43, 51, 54, 0.91)',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

.inner-container{
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(68, 84, 99, 0.64);
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 1px #75899B;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.5)', endColorstr='rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.5)',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
.search-form{
    display: table;
    padding: 8px;
}
.search-form input[type=text]{
    height: 39px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.search-form input[type=text]::-ms-clear{
    display:none;
}
.search-form .pax{
    width: 116px;
}
.hotel-list{
    height: 43px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
    padding: 7px;
    width: 183px;
}
.with-hotel-list{
    margin-right: 5px !important;
    width: 128px;
}
.with-hotel-list-cal-icon{
    right: 9px !important;
}
.search-form input[type=button]{
    width: 118px;
    height: 39px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 64px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid #424040;
    font-family: sagoe-ui-light;
    font-size:24px;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;

    background: #ec5143; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2VjNTE0MyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNjNzNmMzEiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ec5143 0%, #c73f31 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ec5143), color-stop(100%,#c73f31)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ec5143 0%,#c73f31 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ec5143 0%,#c73f31 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ec5143 0%,#c73f31 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ec5143 0%,#c73f31 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ec5143', endColorstr='#c73f31',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
.search-form input[type=button]:hover{
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
    background: #ea877e; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ea877e 0%, #c44b42 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ea877e), color-stop(100%,#c44b42)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ea877e 0%,#c44b42 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ea877e 0%,#c44b42 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ea877e 0%,#c44b42 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ea877e 0%,#c44b42 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ea877e', endColorstr='#c44b42',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #C44B08;
}
.search-form input[type=text]:focus{
    transition: outline 0.3s,box-shadow 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #23D9FC;
    outline: #23D9FC;
}   
.search-input-wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
}
.icon-wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
.icon-wrapper .input-icon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    right: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-wrapper label{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 33px;
    font-family: sagoe-ui-light;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #808080;
    color: #B9B9B9;
}
.more-search{
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 11px;
    color: #FFF;
    top: 18px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'sagoe-ui-light';
    right: 155px;
}
.more-search:hover{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #23D9FC;
    transition: text-shadow 0.3s ease;
}
.search-pax{
    background-image:url("../images/pax.png");
    width: 28px;
    height: 17px;
    top:13px !important;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

[image: Sample Rendering]

To fix the above problem I have to manually configure the margin I keep to the button. How can I fix this to take effect same way in different screen resolutions?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cNHF/)

Comment: As i saw your fiddle, there is no pblm in it. I check it in different resolution and it is coming good for me. Where is the prroblem?

Comment: the problem occurs in different browsers in different pcs using different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be isolated to Firefox and from what I can tell isn't related to resolution (from my testing it works in Chrome and IE9).

There's a lot of invalid and IE specific CSS that Firefox doesn't seem to handle well.

The source of the layout issue however appears to be

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 .search-form input[type="button"] { margin-left: 117px; r}
}
```

Where you're applying a margin only for Firefox. Removing this will fix the wrapping of the search button.

The secondary problem is that the width of the form is different in Firefox which causes the "more search options" to be positioned incorrectly. The quick and dirty fix for that would be to use the same hack as above to change the position of that element.

E.g.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .more-search {right: 190px;}
}
```

Not an ideal solution but if you are pressed for time and need a quick fix that's probably your best bet without doing a more thorough clean-up of the CSS and HTML.